# How to identify the FAP in runway during Landing?

Tags: landing

How to identify the FAP in runway during Landing ?

Comment: What do you mean by "identify"? on a plate or visually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final approach point is part of an instrument approach and thus can be identified using navaids as outlined in the approach procedure.